# ANSIBLE - shell task returns non-zero return code but otherwise works in terminal

Tags: bash, shell, ansible

I have an ansible task:

```
  - name: Get vault's binary path
    shell: type -p vault
    register: vault_binary_path
```

returns

```
 TASK [update_vault : Get vault's binary path] **********************************************************************************************************************************************************************
fatal: [xxxxx]: FAILED! => {"changed": true, "cmd": "type -p vault", "delta": "0:00:00.003303", "end": "2020-04-08 11:37:19.636528", "msg": "non-zero return code", "rc": 1, "start": "2020-04-08 11:37:19.633225", "stderr": "", "stderr_lines": [], "stdout": "", "stdout_lines": []}
```

but when I run it in shell it returns just fine

```
[root@ip-xxxxx]# type -p vault
/usr/local/bin/vault
```

I run ansible as root with **become: true**. All previous steps are fine up until this one. Any advice appreciated.

Comment: An exit status of 1 probably means that ansible's PATH doesn't include `/usr/local/bin`. You'd have a different one if no `type` were found.

Comment: See https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/faq.html#how-can-i-set-the-path-or-any-other-environment-variable-for-a-task-or-entire-playbook re: setting `PATH` from ansible. Regardless, to make this definitively answerable, we'd want you to print `ansible_env.PATH` and include its value in the question.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy thanks, getting "msg": "/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin"

Comment: @CharlesDuffy setting PATH worked, thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define an update to your `PATH` in your playbook:

```yaml
environment:
  PATH: "{{ ansible_env.PATH }}:/usr/local/bin"
```

...so that `/usr/local/bin` is guaranteed to be included.

(Also, while when writing bash-specific code `type` is almost always preferable to `which`, this isn't such a case, as your `shell` may be `/bin/sh`, which isn't guaranteed to support any features that aren't given in the POSIX sh specification. Consider changing to `shell: command -v vault`, which is guaranteed to work as-intended on all POSIX-compliant shells).